# vaadin declarative, how to get the java instance of TextField

Tags: vaadin, declarative, jmix

I am new with declarative UI in vaadin,
how to get the java instance like TextField that was declare in xml ?

I want to set value to it. not found how to get it.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Is your question about Vaadin 8 or newer versions of the Vaadin framework. You refer to xml, which indicates Vaadin 7 or 8, but it would be good to know for sure.

Comment: I am using jmix 1.2 that if not mistake using vaadin 23.
using declarative xml UI but not using @ID annotation is not there

Comment: JournalEdit.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    @Id("custNameField")
            ^
  symbol:   method value()
  location: @interface Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the @Id annotation

```
@Id("my-textfield")
private TextField myTextfield;
```

Please read the documentation:

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/templates/components

Comment: is there anyone know, does it work for jmix too ?
I cant fine @Id annotation in jmix

Comment: https://docs.jmix.io/jmix/ui/screens/annotations.html

Answer (score 1):

For Jmix, you can directly inject the field in screen controllers by using `@Autowired` annotation.

You can find examples here: https://demo.jmix.io/sampler/#main/3/sample?id=textfield-trim

Notice: the injects property name should be the same as `id` property in the XML.

btw, you can ask Jmix questions on https://forum.jmix.io